# One URI per line mean? (Google Oauth)

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

[image]

As stated in the developers console it says one uri per line. As far as I know it only redirects to the first one. How can you utilize this properly?

It feels weird that it allows multiple origins but does not support callbacks specific to those callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that the callback is set by the application, the uri list only checks to make sure it is a valid address.

Answer (score 1):

When you make your auth request, you can specify whatever redirect URI you wish to use.

In the Developers Console, you must register all possible redirect URIs, which is why you can register more than one.  If you use an unregistered redirect URI in your auth request, you will get an error.

For an interactive demo, try the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). You can edit it to use your own OAuth client and redirect URIs.